# WordPress - Elementor - Custom Sticky Toc issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor, sticky

I would like to create a TOC (Table of content) in my blog and make it when user scrolling down it will sticky there.

I have try the codes in notepad & w3school (Try it yourself) both can work.
But when I put the HTML, CSS, and Jquery into the Elementor "HTML" element it cannot work.

My code as below:

````
    <style>
        /* Style for the sticky table of contents */
        .CaseStudyTable {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 20px; /* Adjust the top value as needed */
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        /* Additional styling for the table of contents */
        .CaseStudyHeading {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .CaseStudyList {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .CaseStudyListItem {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .CaseStudyLink {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #007bff;
        }

        .CaseStudyLink:hover {
            color: #0056b3;
        }
    </style>    
<div class="CaseStudyTable">
        <div class="CaseStudyHeading">Table of Contents</div>
        <ul class="CaseStudyList">
            <li class="CaseStudyListItem"><a class="CaseStudyLink" href="#CaseStudySection1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li class="CaseStudyListItem"><a class="CaseStudyLink" href="#CaseStudySection2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li class="CaseStudyListItem"><a class="CaseStudyLink" href="#CaseStudySection3">Section 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.CaseStudyLink').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = $(this).attr('href');
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
                }, 800);
            });
        });
    </script>```

Thanks for your help~


I want to know where I did wrong.
````